# Python multiprocessing stops

Tags: python-2.7, multiprocessing

I am a novice user of a cluster running in RedHat Enterprise Linux. I run python script (version 2.6.5) by using bsub command. Somehow this python program just stops during the multiprocessing. The program goes like:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import multiprocessing

def pop_genomics(chrom):
    os.system('run analysis on DNA')
    os.system('run analysis on DNA')
    os.system('run analysis on DNA')
    os.system('run analysis on DNA')
    print 'Finished!'
    return 'Done'

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count())
finalfiledirs=pool.map(pop_genomics, chroms)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

I get 'Finished!' message from all workers, but this program does not proceed beyond that 'finalfiledirs=pool.map(pop_genomics, chroms)' line. Can you suggest why this is happening?

Comment: Try making your `pop_genomics()` routines write to text files at its start and just before returning. You'll be able to examine the text files to see if any of your subprocesses are hanging, which would cause your main script to hang on `pool.join()`. Also, consider replacing `os.system()` with [subprocess.call()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call). It's been around since Python 2.4, and replaces `os.system()`.

Answer (score -2):

You should be getting an error on that line because on the

```
pool.map(pop_genomics,chroms)
```

you never pass any parameters to pop_genomics, so you need to add some so it would be:

```
pool.map(pop_genomics(parameters),chroms)
```

Comment: pool.map(pop_genomics,chroms) seems to receive the parameters just fine. pool.map takes one input from chroms and feeds into each worker